# MSBuild Dependency on Project in same Solution

Tags: unit-testing, msbuild, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 RC and am trying to configure unit testing with xUnit. In VS2015, with MyProject and MyProject.Tests both in the solution, in src and test folders respectively, I could add a dependency in the project.json file of the tests project:

```
...
"MyProject": "1.0.0",
...
```

This will then allow me to reference the main project:

```
using xunit;
using moq;
using MyProject.Models;
...
Mock<MyModel> mock = new Mock<MyModel>();
...
```

In VS17, with MSBuild and exactly the same configuration, how do I setup a dependency on the main project in the test project?

Answer (score 2):

Sorted. `ProjectReference`'s need to go in a separate `ItemGroup` to `PackageReference`'s.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The IDE can add these too. Under MyProject.Test, right click Dependencies and select Add Reference, Projects, and (browse if needed, then) select the necessary project.